# Select unique results and null

Tags: sql

I need get all lines from table, that have unique value in certain fields and all lines, than have `null` in this fields. Example:

```
id | name | group
-----------------
1  | One  | 1
2  | Two  | null
3  | Three| 3
4  | Four | 2
5  | Five | 1
6  | Six  | 2
7  | Seven| null
```

Result:

```
id | name | group
-----------------
1  | One  | 1
2  | Two  | null
3  | Three| 3
4  | Four | 2
7  | Seven| null
```

How to make it in one request?

Comment: What is the logic that selected "Four" over "Six"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.id, t.name, t.`group`
from tablename t 
join (select `group`, min(id) as mid
      from tablename
      where `group` is not null
      group by `group`) x on x.mid = t.id and x.`group` = t.`group`
union all 
select id, name, `group` 
from tablename
where `group` is null
```

Comment: You do need the `JOIN`